# robomongo aws ec2 ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, robo3t

Trying to make a remote connection from Robomongo to my ec2 ubuntu mongodb.  I have been able to make connections to other non-ec2 ubuntu servers with Robomongo.  But when I try with ec2 I keep getting the "you skipped authorization" error.  I can remote connect to it in the terminal, but not with Robomongo.  Is there something I a missing with ec2 remote connections?

What I have done:

1. created a mongo user administrator
2. make a connection within Robomongo

I am able to connect but says I skipped authorization.

My mongo log reads:

Failed to authenticate neil@admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document

Comment: I have the same problem. I can authenticate through the terminal, but I can not through Robomongo and PHP Mongo module.

Comment: This makes sense.  Thanks for the explanation.  I am newbie to this stuff. -- I will install an earlier version of mongo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Robomongo (at least `0.8.4`) does not support Mongo 3.0 at this time.
For PHP, just update mongo.so module via pecl, because only `1.6` version is fully support Mongo 3.0.

https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/766